# php to pick up the specific query information from array

Tags: php, sql-server, arrays, loops, foreach

```
 <?php

echo "Connecting Database <br>";
$server = 'UKVDEMO03'; //Here you're server
$database = 'smtpFetch';//here the database you want to connect to
$user = 'shoaibsg';//here te user WHO HAS THE RIGHT PERMISSIONS AT THE DATABASE
$pass = '1111111';//and here the user's password
$dsn = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=$server;Database=$database;";
$connect = odbc_connect($dsn, $user, $pass); 
echo "Successfully connected....";

//getting subscribe user detail
$subQuery="select emailAddress, dataSet from userDetail";
$subRes=odbc_exec($connect, $subQuery);
$ix=odbc_num_rows($subRes);
//$newArray[]=$newArray array;
$row[]=array();
$newArrayD[]=$row;
$i=0;
$xc=0;
if($ix>0)
{

    while($row=odbc_fetch_array($subRes))
    {
            $newArrayD[$row['emailAddress']] =$row['emailAddress'];
            $newArrayD[$row['dataSet']] =$row['dataSet'];
    }

}
foreach($newArrayD as $arrayD)
{ $i++; 
echo "<br> -" . $arrayD;
echo "-i increment -" . $i;
}


?>
```

The above displays the below output

-Array
 -shoaib@xyz.com
 -SSCRUS_CS2002
 -nick@xyz.com
 -SSCE_CS2002

Now the problem: if I need to display only the emailAddress only in foreach loop it only displays the first character (I used below in foreach loop)

```
echo "<br> -" . $arrayD['emailAddress'];
```

such as above output displays as 
 -
 -s
 -S
 -n
 -S

I am baffled, please please help

Answer (score 0):

Your code to generate the array is off. Try this:

```
while ($row=odbc_fetch_array($subRes))
{
    $newArrayD[$row['dataSet']] = $row['emailAddress'];
    // This would generate for example $newArrayD['SSCRUS_CS2002'] = 'shoaib@xyz.com'
}
```

Then, to display them, iterate through the array:

```
foreach ($newArrayD as $dataset=>$emailaddress)
{
    echo "- $emailaddress<br />";
}
```

**EDIT - To save both in seperate arrays:**

```
$newArrayD = array('dataset' => array(), 'emails' => array());

while ($row=odbc_fetch_array($subRes))
{
    $newArrayD['dataset'][] = $row['dataSet'];
    $newArrayD['emails'][] = $row['emailAddress'];
}
```

To iterate through the emails:

```
foreach ($newArrayD['emails'] as $emailaddress)
{
    // Code you wish to execute
}
```

To iterate through the datasets:

```
foreach ($newArrayD['dataset'] as $dataset)
{
    // Code you wish to execute
}
```

Using this method, the `$newArrayD['dataset'][0]` will be the dataset linked to `$newArrayD['emails'][0]` etc.

Comment: Thanks for update, actually I need both in my result set(emailAddress and dataSet) and want to use the emailAddress in the first stage and use the dataset latter in the code for some other validations. Is there a way I can keep both in my loop and used the one I want use it first from array for e.g emailAddress and used the dataSet latter.

Comment: @ShoaibSuleman Edited my answer. It might suit your needs a bit more now.

Comment: I've change the logic in the code which actually resolves the issue I was experiencing. But Thank you very much as it will be very helpful for me ...you are star...Thanks